# R, subset two data frames with different rows

Tags: r

```
df1 <-  
Year Month
2011  08
2011  08
2011  09
2011  10
2012  11
2012  11

df2 <-
Year Month
2001  02
2011  08
2011  10
2013  01
2012  11
```

My goal is to make data matrix with (Month, Year) that are common to both data sets.

```
goal <-
Year Month
2011    10
2011    08
2012    11
```

Can anyone please help me???

Answer (score 4):

You can `merge()` the two then find the unique rows.

```
unique(merge(df1, df2))
#   Year Month
# 1 2011    10
# 2 2011     8
# 4 2012    11
```

Comment: thank you but it doesn't work for me, when I try it, R stops,

Comment: R keeps stopping the function when I use that function

Comment: @james That happens even with your example data, above?

Answer (score 2):

If you load dplyr, you can take the intersection

```
library(dplyr)

intersect(df1,df2)
#   Year Month
# 1 2011     8
# 2 2011    10
# 3 2012    11
```

which I find intuitive.